# How can i change variable in controller with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How can i change variable in controller with ajax
**Controller:**

```
$basl = array(2018,11,18,0,0);
$deger = 3;

$baslamatarihi=Carbon::create($basl[0],$basl[1],$basl[2],$basl[3],$basl[4]);
$bitistarihi =Carbon::create($basl[0],$basl[1],$basl[2],$basl[3],$basl[4])->addDay($deger);
```

**Script.js**

```
$("a.sol").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/postajax',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {sayi: 3},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("ok");
        }
    });
}
```

How can i change the `$basl[2]` variable with ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function like this:

## php

### controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
     public function store(Request $request)
     {
        $basl[2] = $request->input('basl');
     }
}
```

### router:

```
Route::post('postajax','CalendarController@store');
```

## jquery

```
$("a.sol").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/postajax',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"basl": "<what you want>"},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("your data changed");
        }
    });
}
```